# webpack.config adding multiple entries with glob.sync

Tags: javascript, webpack, glob

I'm trying to add multiple entry points to my webpack.config file, but I'm having trouble getting it to work right.  My idea was basically:

```
    var entryPoints = glob.sync('./Scripts/**.ts').reduce(function (obj, el) {
      obj[path.parse(el).name] = el;
      return obj
    }, {});
    entryPoints.push({
      a: path.join(__dirname, 'Content/a.scss'),
      b: path.join(__dirname, 'Content/b.scss'),}
);

    module.exports = {
      mode: 'development',
      devtool: 'source-map',
      entry: entryPoints,
...
```

but doing this i just get a 'TypeError: entryPoints.push is not a function'.

is there another better way to do what i want?  And to answer perhaps another question, i don't want all the files in 'content/**.scss' to be included, only a small subset of files in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
entryPoints.a = ...;
entryPoints.b = ...;
```

Comment: Thank you.  surprised there isn't an easier way.

Comment: You could use an object with a and b as the accumulator in your reduce.

Comment: You could also do `['a','b'].forEach(key => { entryPoints[key] = path.join(__dirname, \`Content/${key}.scss\`); });`

Answer (score 1):

After you have completed `reduce` `entryPoints` become an object, and objects don't have a `push` method. In order to add a key-value pair to an object, you need to use either square brackets syntax like `obj["name"] = "Ivan"` or dot syntax like `obj.name = "Ivan"`.